# $POST data in $SESSIONS

Tags: php, session, post

Why it's not working?

**index.php**:

```
<strong>Your name:</strong>
<form action="name.php" method"post">
  <input type="text" name="username"/>
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit!" />
</form>
<?php 
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['post-data'] = $_POST;
?>
```

**name.php**:

```
<strong>Your name is:</strong>
<strong>
  <?php 
    session_start();
    echo $_SESSION['post-data'];
  ?>
</strong>
```

**name.php** print me:

> Your name is: Array

How can I fix this?

Comment: Try to use print_r to understand or echo $_SESSION['post-data']['username'];

Comment: `session_start();` before HTML

Comment: Session is always in Array you can't `echo` Session variable using `$_SESSION['post-data']`

Comment: @Kitson88 i put session_start before html, but not work again

Comment: @jimmynew see my answer below.

Comment: It is not working, because you are trying to access submitted form data _that has not been submitted yet_ ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, `session_start();` should always be placed at the top of your document before any HTML has been loaded.

**index.php**

```
//No need to start session here as no $_SESSION variables needed. 

<strong>Your name:</strong>
<form action="name.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="username"/>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit!" />
</form>
```

Secondly, assign your `$_POST` data after it's been posted to `name.php` and then assign it to a `$_SESSION`

**name.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
?>

<strong>Your name is:</strong>
<strong><?php echo $_SESSION['username'];?></strong>
```

If you want see whats inside an array for debug purposes then you can use `var_dump()`.

**Example of `var_dump()`**

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

or

```
var_dump($_SESSION);
```